# Google BigQuery SQL Error - Cannot access field 2 on a value with type FLOAT64 at [5:47]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Could really use some help. I went through my code and made sure I have the correct punctuation and did everything exactly as displayed in the lesson I am taking. Still receiving an error. Here is the code:

```
SELECT 
    usertype,
    CONCAT(start_station_name, " to ", end_station_name) AS route, 
    COUNT(*) as num_trips,
    ROUND(AVG(cast(tripduration as int64)/60).2) AS duration
FROM 
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` 
GROUP BY 
    start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
ORDER BY 
    num_trips DESC 
LIMIT 
    10
```

> ERROR Cannot access field 2 on a value with type FLOAT64 at [5:47]

Comment: replace `dot` with `comma` in `ROUND(AVG(cast(tripduration as int64)/60).2) AS duration`

Answer (score 0):

The round function uses a comma not a dot. You should change the dot before the 2 to a comma.